# Add Google event tracking code on dynamic AngularJS button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics

I have the following button scheme for my Angular webapp:

```
<a ng-if="ProductSaleLink" target="_blank" href="myaffilatelink.com" class="ng-scope"><i class="icon-action-cart"></i><span>BUY NOW</span></a>
```

I want to use the following Google Analytics event tracking code for the above links.

```
ga('send', 'event', 'buy-now', 'my-pages-1');
```

How can I add dynamic tracking code to my AngularJS webapp?

Comment: You could create a directive and register a click event on the element to track the click. Have the relevant values as attribute value of the element and read them and pass it on to the ga function in the click handler. If you want to perform on other events as well, then just have the event name as well in the attribute.

Comment: Thanks. Have you a sample for that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use already existing angularjs modules for Google analytics, such as **[Angulartics](http://luisfarzati.github.io/angulartics/#/getting-started)**. Once installed and included as a module in your angular app, you can follow getting started instructions for that, you can add specific attributes to track events as follows:

`<a href="file.pdf" analytics-on="click" analytics-event="buy-now">Buy now</a>`

If you want help with writing your own directive for this, I'll be glad to help you out :).